# Comparison of items in two ArrayLists and return differences

Tags: c#, arraylist, compare

I'm currently writing a simple app to compare two lists and return differences if any are found.

Note - [int] imaginary index for the purpose of this explanation

```
//---------------Prep----------------------------
            ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList storage = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();
            string path = Application.ExecutablePath;
            string root = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
//---------------END Prep------------------------
//---------------Load content into list1------------------------
StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(root + "/healthy.txt");
            string sLine = "";

            while (sLine != null)
            {
                sLine = objReader.ReadLine();
                if (sLine != null)
                    list1.Add(sLine);
            }
            objReader.Close();
//---------------END Load content into list1------------------------

//---------------Load content into list2------------------------
 string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(root, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                storage.Add(file.ToString());
            }
            foreach (string sOutput2 in storage)
            {
                list2.Add(GetMD5HashFromFile(sOutput2));
            }

//---------------END Load content into list2------------------------
```

I tried everything, but it seems that I cannot crack this.. How do I ''loop'' through both lists and compare each item side by side in order then return the one's in list two that do not match the control list(list one)?

Logically the program would return ''More work'' as the wrong entry, because both "music" and "more work" are in the third row of their respective lists, they get checked and do not match. List 1 is control, so list 2's entry gets recorded as the odd one out.

Now I have tried it right and left, but I cannot make it happen.. Anyone out there who would be willing to shed some light on this or perhaps even guide me through to the right answer?

Many thanks

EDIT: Added my code for both arrayLists, im only missing the comparison function...

No particular reason for using ArrayList, any suggestions that would make this process easier are very welcome.

Comment: Why ArrayList?  Are you still using Fx 1.x ? Can you use LINQ? And please add something more like real code as example. Is Docs an array? Note that you have an _edit_ button.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using ArrayList?

Comment: Are the lists sorted? Given the lists `{1, 2, 4}` and `{1, 2, 3, 4}`, should the result be `3`? If the lists aren't sorted, is `{1, 2, 3}` considered the same as `{3, 2, 1}`?

Comment: The lists will ALWAYS have the same number of items. Never will List1 have 4 items and List2 have 5.

Comment: If you could get these items into an [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) instead of an [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) things would become much simpler (using either the [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) method or [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) method for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, let's use a more modern way to read the lines:

```
IEnumerable<string> list1 = File.ReadLines("file1");
IEnumerable<string> list2 = Directory.EnumerateFiles("folder", 
       SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

And then the list of files from list2 that are not in list1 :

```
IList<string> difference = list2.Except(list1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  ArrayList diffs = new ArrayList();
  for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
  if(!one.Item(i).equals(two.Item(i))  )
     diffs.Add(two.Item(i));
  }
```

N = number of items coomon to both lists.
diffs = the arraylist with the odd ones of list two

If you want only the first odd entry from list two , then add a `break` into the loop. Here , the type of objects in the list is assumed to have defined an appropriate `equals(Object obj)`method.

Answer (score 0):

Between these you can get the results you want.

```
IEnumerable<object> result = one.ToArray().Intersect(two.ToArray()); //Gives you what is the same
one.ToArray().Except(two.ToArray()); //Gives you wants in one not two
two.ToArray().Except(one.ToArray()); //Gives you wants in two and not in one
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple loop with integers that should work with any version the the framework.

If you have custom objects, here are guidelines for overriding Equals:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
 ArrayList left = new ArrayList();
 ArrayList right = new ArrayList();

 left.Add(1);
 left.Add(2);
 left.Add(3);

 right.Add(1);
 right.Add(2);
 right.Add(4);

 bool areEqual = CompareArrayList(left, right);

        private bool CompareArrayList(ArrayList left, ArrayList right)
        {

            if (left == null && right == null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (left == null || right == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (left.Count != right.Count)
            {
                return false;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < left.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!left[i].Equals(right[i]))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;

        }
```